# Increasing re-planning frequency of Nav2 global planner

Tags: ros2, nav2, global-planner

I'm trying to increase the re-planning frequency of Nav2's A* global planner from 1 Hz to 10 Hz. In order to do this, I changed the `expected_planner_frequency` parameter from `1.0` to `10.0` in the `planner_server` section of `nav2_params.yaml`.

However, running `ros2 topic hz` on the global planner still shows a re-planning frequency of 1 Hz. Looking a little more into the code, it seems like changing `expected_planner_frequency` only affects whether a warning message will be displayed if the planner server is unable to compute a global path within `1/expected_planner_frequency` seconds, and doesn't actually affect the global planner's re-planning frequency (i.e. the number of times it actually computes a path from start to goal each second).

As such, I wanted to ask how I can update the global planner's re-planning frequency. Is it a parameter I can set in `nav2_params.yaml` or do I need to modify the XML files that control Nav2's behavior tree? Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in the behavior tree XML. The BT is where the navigation behavior is defined and customizable. The current default has a RateController over the planner to limit it to a fixed rate (1 hz), though you can use any other type of BT logic to define replanning events.